# vscode - the options for supporting schema validation

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

We want to create new vscode extension that adds a new json validation for our schema

After looking at the vs-code docs we saw the following options:

> 1 . contribute the schema to [`json-schema store`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/json#_json-schemas-and-settings) and vs code will
> load it automatically
>
> 2. use the [json contribution point](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.jsonValidation)

Please correct me if im wrong...

Since we are new to vs code extension development , are those two options is the **only options** that we have?
we want to **consider all the options** that vs code have to support this scenario ...

Comment: "even it's not clean" - Not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: @Gama11 - Thanks for your response , please ignore it, we need any other solution/workaround to support it (beside those two options...)

Comment: Why do you need a workaround / what's wrong with using one of these options? I don't think there are others.